# react.js and webpack 2, need a solution

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack-2

I am doing a sample tutorial with create-react-app and webpack 2, but I am receiving this error:

[image]

This is my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-latest-minimal": "^1.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "react-scripts": "0.8.5",
    "sass-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "svgo-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    app: '../src/index.jsx', 

  },
  output: {
    path: './build',
    filename: 'app.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'html-loader',
    query: {
      minimize: true
    }
  },{
      test: /(\.jsx?)$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      query: {
        presets: ['latest-minimal', 'react'],
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    },{
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'file-loader'
      }, {
        loader: 'svgo-loader',
        options: {
          plugins: [{
            removeTitle: true
          }, {
            convertColors: {
              shorthex: false
            }
          }, {
            convertPathData: false
          }]
        }
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

And my index.jsx:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from './App.jsx';

render(<App />, document.getElementByClass('App'));
```

Comment: You're running React in Node, but you have to run the code in a browser.

Comment: You need to build the bundle using Webpack in node and then view the application in the browser. At the console, you need to run Webpack command to build and then run Webpack dev server.

Comment: The error gives me, after running the webpack command

Comment: check this repo i have created boilerplate which uses create-react-app structure and uses webpack 2 you can grab configs from there or add your components inside it.
https://github.com/sagarrabadiya/react-boilerplate

Comment: also you need to eject from create-react-app if you want to customise all the behaviour.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

create-react-app was written for webpack 1.  You have updated to webpack 2 which only came out a month ago.  There are some syntax changes that break version 1 webpack.config.js files.  Here is a migration guide:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/

Answer (score 0):

I have created a bolierplate which uses create-react-app and uses webpack 2
you can take configurations from there.

https://github.com/sagarrabadiya/react-boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

If you still haven't found one I think [this](https://github.com/ModusCreateOrg/budgeting-sample-app-webpack2) is pretty good